# Filter on related table with Laravel and eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My method is:

```
public function show(Tag $tag)
{
    $posts = $tag->posts;
    return view('posts.index',compact('posts'));
}
```

It works fine but i want to get the posts where posts->user_id is the authenticated user.

```
public function show(Tag $tag)
{
    $posts = $tag->posts()->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id);
    return view('posts.index',compact('posts'));
}
```

How do i filter on the related posts table?

this is a many to many relationship with a pivot table present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have should work, but don't forget to `get()` the results after adding your where:

```
$posts = $tag->posts()->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Comment: Don't think that's gonna work since it's a many to many relationship and the post table has no `user_id`

Comment: it worked!. Posts table HAS a user_id and there is a pivot table post_tag between them

Comment: Ah I see. I thought post to user was a many-to-many relation but thinking about it know that wouldn't make much sense ;)